# Querying ContentFolderItem through REST API only returns first 500 items and next page is empty

Tags: rest-api

I have a very simple SOQL query:

```
SELECT Id, IsFolder, ParentContentFolderId, Title FROM ContentFolderItem WHERE ParentContentFolderId IN ('ContentWorkspace.RootContentFolderId','ContentWorkspace.RootContentFolderId')
```

(The `ContentWorkspace.RootContentFolderId` are actual values from 2 Content libraries).

When i use Apex to run this SOQL, i get 2504 items (as i expect).

When i use REST API, ( `/services/data/v47.0/query` in either 46 or 47), the first page contains just 500 items (instead of usual 2000 like it does for all other queries) and a `nextRecordsUrl`, but when i follow `nextRecordsUrl` the response is empty like so:

```
{"totalSize":2504,"done":true,"records":[]}
```

Is there some kind of limit on the number of `ContentFolderItem` that can be queried via REST API specifically?

This is in `Developer` edition.

Comment: FYI -- the "chunk size" is variable and computed by SFDC based on the byte-intensity of the response so values less than 2000 are expected.  This doesn't answer your question though, just context.

Comment: @cropredy fair enough, my code is written to handle any page size and is using absence of `nextRecordsUrl` as a signal for 'no more pages'